# Google Sheets UNIQUE not removing all duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a table in which the headers should be all the unique start and end times that are in another table. However, when I use the UNIQUE function, the result still contains duplicates. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

This is the formula I'm using:

`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B3:B,E3:E)),UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B3:B,E3:E))<>""),1,1))`

[image: spreadsheet with problem]

As you can see, there are duplicate values for 04:00 and 05:00.

I've checked to make sure the values are all formatted the same way but I'm still getting this problem.

Here's the link to a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0DgVzoXLrxauKuPmjUO5kilKj2Uwjwp4ppmcHEfxAI/edit#gid=0) with the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from using the FILTER function. It uses relative positions.

Use the QUERY function instead:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:B,E3:E),"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"))))
```